# Google Maps SVG marker with animation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can’t get this SVG to animate as a marker on Google Maps

```html
<svg width="120px" height="120px" viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.3">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50">
      <animate attributeName="r" begin="0s" dur="3s" values="0;50" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.1,0.2,0.3,1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      <animate attributeName="stroke-opacity" begin="0s" dur="3s" values="0;.3;.3;0" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
    </circle>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30">
      <animate attributeName="r" begin="-1s" dur="3s" values="0;50" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.1,0.2,0.3,1" calcMode="spline" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      <animate attributeName="stroke-opacity" begin="-1s" dur="3s" values="0;.3;.3;0" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: set the `optimized`-option of the marker to `false`

Comment: @Dr.Molle can u add that as the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, set `optimized: false` in the marker options.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerOptions):

> Disable
>   optimized rendering for animated GIFs or PNGs, or when each marker
>   must be rendered as a separate DOM element (advanced usage only).

Comment: heh, i appreciate the troll 